NextJS builds locally but gives error when run Docker
I have 2 apps written in NextJS, both with the same configs and Dockerfile except for ports, and the first one is being built successfully both locally and in Docker, the second one is giving me this error when built in Docker. I have the default Dockerfile from nextjs and changed only the exported port to 3003 and not 3000.
#0 building with "desktop-linux" instance using docker driver

#1 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
#1 transferring dockerfile: 1.63kB done
#1 DONE 0.0s

#2 resolve image config for docker.io/docker/dockerfile:1
#2 DONE 0.3s

#3 docker-image://docker.io/docker/dockerfile:1@sha256:865e5dd094beca432e8c0a1d5e1c465db5f998dca4e439981029b3b81fb39ed5
#3 CACHED

#4 [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:18-alpine
#4 DONE 0.4s

#5 [internal] load .dockerignore
#5 transferring context: 2B done
#5 DONE 0.0s

#6 [base 1/1] FROM docker.io/library/node:18-alpine@sha256:a25c1e4ecc284985f4cbc449021e9259560c644dd9611e5a72d9c4750f24f6c7
#6 DONE 0.0s

#7 [internal] load build context
#7 transferring context: 44.94kB 0.0s done
#7 DONE 0.0s

#8 [deps 4/4] RUN   if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn;   else echo "Lockfile not found." && exit 1;   fi
#8 CACHED

#9 [deps 1/4] RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
#9 CACHED

#10 [deps 2/4] WORKDIR /app
#10 CACHED

#11 [deps 3/4] COPY package.json yarn.lock* package-lock.json* pnpm-lock.yaml* .npmrc* ./
#11 CACHED

#12 [builder 1/4] WORKDIR /app
#12 CACHED

#13 [builder 2/4] COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
#13 CACHED

#14 [builder 3/4] COPY . .
#14 DONE 0.2s

#15 [builder 4/4] RUN   if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn run build;   else echo "Lockfile not found." && exit 1;   fi
#15 0.312 yarn run v1.22.19
#15 0.324 $ next build
#15 0.727 Attention: Next.js now collects completely anonymous telemetry regarding usage.
#15 0.727 This information is used to shape Next.js' roadmap and prioritize features.
#15 0.727 You can learn more, including how to opt-out if you'd not like to participate in this anonymous program, by visiting the following URL:
#15 0.727 https://nextjs.org/telemetry
#15 0.727
#15 0.782    Skipping validation of types
#15 0.782    Skipping linting
#15 0.936    Creating an optimized production build ...
#15 2.772 Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
#15 2.772   npx update-browserslist-db@latest
#15 2.772   Why you should do it regularly: https://github.com/browserslist/update-db#readme
#15 10.99 Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
#15 10.99   npx browserslist@latest --update-db
#15 10.99   Why you should do it regularly: https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#browsers-data-updating
#15 12.67  ✓ Compiled successfully
#15 12.67    Collecting page data ...
#15 13.34 AxiosError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
#15 13.34     at AxiosError.from (file:///app/node_modules/axios/lib/core/AxiosError.js:89:14)
#15 13.34     at RedirectableRequest.handleRequestError (file:///app/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:606:25)
#15 13.34     at RedirectableRequest.emit (node:events:529:35)
#15 13.34     at eventHandlers.<computed> (/app/node_modules/follow-redirects/index.js:14:24)
#15 13.34     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:517:28)
#15 13.34     at Socket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:501:9)
#15 13.34     at Socket.emit (node:events:517:28)
#15 13.34     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
#15 13.34     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
#15 13.34     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
#15 13.34   port: 80,
#15 13.34   address: '127.0.0.1',
#15 13.34   syscall: 'connect',
#15 13.34   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
#15 13.34   errno: -111,
#15 13.34   config: {
#15 13.34     transitional: {
#15 13.34       silentJSONParsing: true,
#15 13.34       forcedJSONParsing: true,
#15 13.34       clarifyTimeoutError: false
#15 13.34     },
#15 13.34     adapter: [ 'xhr', 'http' ],
#15 13.34     transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
#15 13.34     transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
#15 13.34     timeout: 5000000,
#15 13.34     xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
#15 13.34     xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
#15 13.34     maxContentLength: -1,
#15 13.34     maxBodyLength: -1,
#15 13.34     env: { FormData: [Function], Blob: [class Blob] },
#15 13.34     validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
#15 13.34     headers: Object [AxiosHeaders] {
#15 13.34       Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
#15 13.34       'Content-Type': 'application/json',
#15 13.34       Authorization: 'Bearer ',
#15 13.34       'User-Agent': 'axios/1.6.0',
#15 13.34       'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, compress, deflate, br'
#15 13.34     },
#15 13.34     baseURL: 'http://localhost',
#15 13.34     params: { language: 'bg', limit: 20 },
#15 13.34     method: 'get',
#15 13.34     url: 'flash-sale',
#15 13.34     data: undefined
#15 13.34   },
#15 13.34   request: <ref *1> Writable {
#15 13.34     _writableState: WritableState {
#15 13.34       objectMode: false,
#15 13.34       highWaterMark: 16384,
#15 13.34       finalCalled: false,
#15 13.34       needDrain: false,
#15 13.34       ending: false,
#15 13.34       ended: false,
#15 13.34       finished: false,
#15 13.34       destroyed: false,
#15 13.34       decodeStrings: true,
#15 13.34       defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
#15 13.34       length: 0,
#15 13.34       writing: false,
#15 13.34       corked: 0,
#15 13.34       sync: true,
#15 13.34       bufferProcessing: false,
#15 13.34       onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
#15 13.34       writecb: null,
#15 13.34       writelen: 0,
#15 13.34       afterWriteTickInfo: null,
#15 13.34       buffered: [],
#15 13.34       bufferedIndex: 0,
#15 13.34       allBuffers: true,
#15 13.34       allNoop: true,
#15 13.34       pendingcb: 0,
#15 13.34       constructed: true,
#15 13.34       prefinished: false,
#15 13.34       errorEmitted: false,
#15 13.34       emitClose: true,
#15 13.34       autoDestroy: true,
#15 13.34       errored: null,
#15 13.34       closed: false,
#15 13.34       closeEmitted: false,
#15 13.34       [Symbol(kOnFinished)]: []
#15 13.34     },
#15 13.34     _events: [Object: null prototype] {
#15 13.34       response: [Function: handleResponse],
#15 13.34       error: [Function: handleRequestError],
#15 13.34       socket: [Array]
#15 13.34     },
#15 13.34     _eventsCount: 3,
#15 13.34     _maxListeners: undefined,
#15 13.34     _options: {
#15 13.34       maxRedirects: 21,
#15 13.34       maxBodyLength: Infinity,
#15 13.34       protocol: 'http:',
#15 13.34       path: '/flash-sale?language=bg&limit=20',
#15 13.34       method: 'GET',
#15 13.34       headers: [Object: null prototype],
#15 13.34       agents: [Object],
#15 13.34       auth: undefined,
#15 13.34       family: undefined,
#15 13.34       beforeRedirect: [Function: dispatchBeforeRedirect],
#15 13.34       beforeRedirects: [Object],
#15 13.34       hostname: 'localhost',
#15 13.34       port: '',
#15 13.34       agent: undefined,
#15 13.34       nativeProtocols: [Object],
#15 13.34       pathname: '/flash-sale',
#15 13.34       search: '?language=bg&limit=20'
#15 13.34     },
#15 13.34     _ended: true,
#15 13.34     _ending: true,
#15 13.34     _redirectCount: 0,
#15 13.34     _redirects: [],
#15 13.34     _requestBodyLength: 0,
#15 13.34     _requestBodyBuffers: [],
#15 13.34     _onNativeResponse: [Function (anonymous)],
#15 13.34     _currentRequest: ClientRequest {
#15 13.34       _events: [Object: null prototype],
#15 13.34       _eventsCount: 7,
#15 13.34       _maxListeners: undefined,
#15 13.34       outputData: [],
#15 13.34       outputSize: 0,
#15 13.34       writable: true,
#15 13.34       destroyed: false,
#15 13.34       _last: true,
#15 13.34       chunkedEncoding: false,
#15 13.34       shouldKeepAlive: false,
#15 13.34       maxRequestsOnConnectionReached: false,
#15 13.34       _defaultKeepAlive: true,
#15 13.34       useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
#15 13.34       sendDate: false,
#15 13.34       _removedConnection: false,
#15 13.34       _removedContLen: false,
#15 13.34       _removedTE: false,
#15 13.34       strictContentLength: false,
#15 13.34       _contentLength: 0,
#15 13.34       _hasBody: true,
#15 13.34       _trailer: '',
#15 13.34       finished: true,
#15 13.34       _headerSent: true,
#15 13.34       _closed: false,
#15 13.34       socket: [Socket],
#15 13.34       _header: 'GET /flash-sale?language=bg&limit=20 HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
#15 13.34         'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
#15 13.34         'Content-Type: application/json\r\n' +
#15 13.34         'Authorization: Bearer \r\n' +
#15 13.34         'User-Agent: axios/1.6.0\r\n' +
#15 13.34         'Accept-Encoding: gzip, compress, deflate, br\r\n' +
#15 13.34         'Host: localhost\r\n' +
#15 13.34         'Connection: close\r\n' +
#15 13.34         '\r\n',
#15 13.34       _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
#15 13.34       _onPendingData: [Function: nop],
#15 13.34       agent: [Agent],
#15 13.34       socketPath: undefined,
#15 13.34       method: 'GET',
#15 13.34       maxHeaderSize: undefined,
#15 13.34       insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
#15 13.34       joinDuplicateHeaders: undefined,
#15 13.34       path: '/flash-sale?language=bg&limit=20',
#15 13.34       _ended: false,
#15 13.34       res: null,
#15 13.34       aborted: false,
#15 13.34       timeoutCb: null,
#15 13.34       upgradeOrConnect: false,
#15 13.34       parser: null,
#15 13.34       maxHeadersCount: null,
#15 13.34       reusedSocket: false,
#15 13.34       host: 'localhost',
#15 13.34       protocol: 'http:',
#15 13.34       _redirectable: [Circular *1],
#15 13.34       [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
#15 13.34       [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
#15 13.34       [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
#15 13.34       [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
#15 13.34       [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype],
#15 13.34       [Symbol(errored)]: null,
#15 13.34       [Symbol(kHighWaterMark)]: 16384,
#15 13.34       [Symbol(kRejectNonStandardBodyWrites)]: false,
#15 13.34       [Symbol(kUniqueHeaders)]: null
#15 13.34     },
#15 13.34     _currentUrl: 'http://localhost/flash-sale?language=bg&limit=20',
#15 13.34     _timeout: null,
#15 13.34     [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
#15 13.34   },
#15 13.34   cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
#15 13.34       at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1555:16) {
#15 13.34     errno: -111,
#15 13.34     code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
#15 13.34     syscall: 'connect',
#15 13.34     address: '127.0.0.1',
#15 13.34     port: 80
#15 13.34   }
#15 13.34 }
#15 13.35
#15 13.35 > Build error occurred
#15 13.35 Error: Failed to collect page data for /flash-sales/[slug]
#15 13.35     at /app/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js:1171:15
#15 13.35     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
#15 13.35   type: 'Error'
#15 13.35 }
#15 13.42 info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
#15 13.42 error Command failed with exit code 1.
#15 ERROR: process "/bin/sh -c if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn run build;   else echo \"Lockfile not found.\" && exit 1;   fi" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
------
 > [builder 4/4] RUN   if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn run build;   else echo "Lockfile not found." && exit 1;   fi:
13.34 }
13.35
13.35 > Build error occurred
13.35 Error: Failed to collect page data for /flash-sales/[slug]
13.35     at /app/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js:1171:15
13.35     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
13.35   type: 'Error'
13.35 }
13.42 info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
13.42 error Command failed with exit code 1.
------
Dockerfile:25
--------------------
  24 |
  25 | >>> RUN \
  26 | >>>   if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn run build; \
  27 | >>>   else echo "Lockfile not found." && exit 1; \
  28 | >>>   fi
  29 |
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn run build;   else echo \"Lockfile not found.\" && exit 1;   fi" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

That's my next.config.js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const { i18n } = require('./next-i18next.config');

module.exports = {
  output: 'standalone',
  reactStrictMode: true,
  i18n,
  images: {
    domains: [
      'localhost',
    ],
  },
  ...(process.env.APPLICATION_MODE === 'development' && {
    typescript: {
      ignoreBuildErrors: true,
    },
    eslint: {
      ignoreDuringBuilds: true,
    },
  }),
};

So far changed ports, node versions, caching node modules and always the same error.

Is this the same problem as React/Next.js docker build failing when trying to reach out to local API endpoint?  An image build can't normally contact other containers at all, and isn't normally running any sort of server.

Not really, I don't have them under the same service and the problem is persisted even with remote hosts.
